# How to test component on select triggered event

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have a component which has a drop down.

When changed it triggers `serviceChanged` function, which filters through an array to get the `selectedProduct` from an array based on the event value.

I want to write unit test code for `serviceChanged` function.

Please suggest me how to write unit test cases to test `serviceChanged` function

My code is as follows:

- Below is my HTML

  ```html
  <select formControlName="selectedService" id="service" (change)="serviceChanged($event)">
      <option value=""  disabled>Select</option>
      <option *ngFor="let service of services" [value]="service.serviceCode">{{service.serviceName}}</option>
  </select>
  ```
- The mock data that I am using for passing servicecode in `serviceChanged` function is as follows:

  ```js
  const data = {   
      "serviceName":"UK 36 Month Mobile - no SIM card",
      "serviceCode":"V240M-DTM-24-MOBILE-UK-B"
  };
  ```
- My function which I am calling on dropdown value change is as follows:

  ```js
  serviceChanged(event: any) {    
      const selectedServiceCode = event.target.value;
      const productIds: string[] = this.serviceProdctMapping[selectedServiceCode];
      if (productIds && productIds.length > 0) {
        this.serviceProducts = this.products.filter(p => productIds.indexOf(p.productCode) > -1);
      } else {
        this.serviceProducts = [];
      }
      const selectedService = this.services.find(s => s.serviceCode === selectedServiceCode);
      this.selectedService = selectedService;
      (this.details.get('service') as FormControl).setValue(selectedService.serviceCode);
      (this.details.get('serviceInfo') as FormControl).setValue(this.selectedService);
  }


  ngOnInit() {   
      this.subscription = this.dtmService.getInitialData().subscribe(data => {
        console.log('sample data', data);
        this.services = data.services;
        this.serviceProdctMapping = data.serviceProduct;
      });
  }
  ```
- Below is my Spec. Ts file

  ```js
  it('Should populate selected service data', () => {
      component.serviceChanged(data.serviceCode);
      expect(component.selectedService).toEqual({ "serviceCode": "V240M-DTM-24-MOBILE-UK-B", "serviceName": "UK 36 Month Mobile - no SIM card"});   
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to mock your dtmService because it is not the subject of your test. You can do something like :

```
@NgModule({
...
 providers: [
{
          provide: DtmService, useValue:
            getInitialData: () =>
              of({   
                "serviceName":"UK 36 Month Mobile - no SIM card",
                "serviceCode":"V240M-DTM-24-MOBILE-UK-B"
              })
        }
]
...
})
```

If you wanna trigger the change event you can do something like:

```
const select = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('select'));
select.nativeElement.value = 'serviceCodeX';
       dispatchEvent(select.nativeElement, 'change');
       fixture.detectChanges();
       tick();
```

Make sure to use `fakeAsync` for that.

Then you create a spy on your function:

```
const spy = spyOn(component, 'serviceChanged');
```

To check if it was called you do like:

```
expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
```

After that you can get references to your other form controls by doing the same as the select and check their content depending on your logic.

Comment: But i am new to write test cases can u plz suggest  name of the file where should i write all code.

Comment: In the spec.ts file inside the component folder. take a look at this 9 minutes read article: https://medium.com/frontend-fun/angular-unit-testing-jasmine-karma-step-by-step-e3376d110ab4